# Play from MTP(Media Tranfert Protocol) device!

Tags: c++, linux, wrapper, device

I developed a wrapper of libmtp in c++ language on linux. Now, i'm looking for a documentation  that explain me if the MTP device can playing a song from MTP library. I've  [this documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fed98ca6-ca7f-4e60-b88c-c5fce88f3eea&displaylang=en) were I did not understand if this play is possible.

Thanks in advance, and excuse me for my English.

Gf.

Comment: Can I do the play function with authentication on DRM??

Answer (score 1):

I have both good and bad news for you.

The good news is that the MTP protocol has well-defined commands to play
back content on a device. Operation 0xD411 (PTP_DPC_MTP_PlaybackObject)
will start playing back a file on the device (whatever that may mean if
this is not a music or video file), and operation 0xD403 can set the
playback volume to save your ears. Then there are operations to
determine how far into the current file you currently are, so as to
support say progress bars.

Since these commands have been around since the dawn of the MTP protocol
and since it was developed in cooperation with Creative Technology, this
is probably a requested feature from the Creative people who already had
support for playback on their devices using the PDE protocol back then.

Anyway, here are the bad news:
[logs]$ grep d411 *
mtp-detect-trekstor-vibez.txt:   0xd411: Playback Object

Aha there is only one known device in the world which actually supports
playback on the device. So either you go buy the Trekstor Vibez, or you
can forget about this. You could always try asking your hardware vendor
of choice to go implement this.

Since none of the core developers of libmtp has the Trekstor device, this
is not yet implemented in libmtp.